# How to connect BMP390 to arduino?

Tags: arduino, atmega, atmega328p

I have a `bmp390` sensor and an official circuit from the manufacturer for connecting it to `i2c`, but there is a problem, the sensor pins are designed for a maximum of `3.6 V`, and the Arduino logic output is `5 V`, how to solve this?
[image]

Documentation from the manufacturer: https://gebrabit.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/bst-bmp390-ds002.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a level shifter. If you don't want to design one, buy a BMP390 module with built-in level shifter.